# onchange protoype function call

Tags: javascript, onchange

file a.js

```
function a(){}
a.prototype.z=function(){console.log('z')};
a.prototype.b=function(){
var elementHtml='<select 
onchange="/* what to fill here to make a call to a.prototype.z */
"><option value="1">call z</option>';
};
```

file b.js

```
var qw= new a();
/* call to function */
document.querySelector("#somediv").innerHTML=qw.b();
```

i need to call a.z from inside a.b.
is this even possible with this design or i should use some other declaration/ design ??.

Comment: You can either bind the onchange (use addEventListener to attach the event) to an instance of `a`, or literally call `a.prototype.z()`.

Comment: remember to close that select with `</select>`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to call `z()` on `qw` object and not directly `a.prototype.z()`.

Your code doesn't work because `var elementHtml='<...'` just creates a string variable and not the DOM element itself.

So most easily, append the string, query for the `select` element and then bind an event listener to it with `addEventListener()`.

```js
function a(){}
a.prototype.z=function(){console.log('z')};
a.prototype.b=function(){
    var elementHtml='<select><option value="1">select</option><option value="2">call z</option>';
    return elementHtml;
};

var qw= new a();
/* call to function */

var div = document.querySelector("#somediv");
div.innerHTML = qw.b();

console.log(div.querySelector('select'));
div.querySelector('select').addEventListener('change', qw.z);
```

```html
<div id="somediv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call using `a.prototype.z()`

```
function a(){}
a.prototype.z=function(){console.log('z')};
a.prototype.b=function(){
var elementHtml='<select onchange="a.prototype.z()"><option value="1">call z</option><option value="2">call b</option>';
return elementHtml; // need to return it
};

var qw= new a();
document.querySelector("#somediv").innerHTML=qw.b();
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/2084eyg0/)